# Inserting an object so the array stays sorted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, lodash

I have an enum of different Steps

```
 export enum StepCategory {
    START = 0,
    POSITION_1 = 1,
    TRANSPORT = 2,
    RECEIVER = 3,
    END = 4,
    NO_STEP_MATCH = 5
}
```

This will later result in an array, where for every Step I have an object. The Problem is I won't load all the information at once, so i can'tdo a simple for-loop and push each item chronogically. I could be that I first load the value for Step 4, so my array would be:

```
var array = [{"END" , "POSITIVE"}]
```

Afterwards I would get the Info for Step 2, then I would have:

```
var array = [{"END", "POSITIVE"}, {"TRANSPORT", "POSITIVE"}]
```

But this is not sorted.

What should I do? Should I declare an array of 6 undefined values

```
var array = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

This way I wouldn't need any sorting-algorithm after each Update, and can just push the value at the right position.

Just some small Info: I use AngularJS 1, Typescript and Lodash

Comment: Why do you declare an enum with the values, but use the literal strings within your objects?

Comment: var array = [{"END", "POSITIVE"}, {"TRANSPORT", "POSITIVE"}]
is this line syntactically correct ??

Comment: why can't you sort the array when you add a step? it's a 6 items length array, it's not going to slow down your application ... it's basically an insertion sort in the best case scenario requiring O(1) swaps

Comment: @Eddi yes it's just for demonstration purpose. There normally is an Object which gets inserted with various fields and information.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could sort it with an object and the assigned values of the key.

```js
var StepCategory = { START: 0, POSITION_1: 1, TRANSPORT: 2, RECEIVER: 3, END: 4,  NO_STEP_MATCH: 5 },
    array = [["END", "POSITIVE"], ["TRANSPORT", "POSITIVE"]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return StepCategory[a[0]] - StepCategory[b[0]];
});

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is - as someone mentioned in the comments - not syntactically correct:

```
var array = [{"END", "POSITIVE"}, {"TRANSPORT", "POSITIVE"}]
```

I assume that this was just a typo writing this question. Additionally if you actually use the enum in your array as key and just left it out for demonstration purposes, I would expect your array of objects to look something like this:

```
var array = [{StepCategory.END: "POSITIVE"}, {StepCategory.TRANSPORT: "POSITIVE"}]
```

In order to sort this with LoDash you could use something like this:

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(array, i => Object.keys(i)[0]);
```

This sorts your array by the value of the first key of each object which refers to your enum value.